# CodeIgniter - Looking for a little help using routes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have had a read over the routing page on the codeigniter site and im still a bit unsure about how to go about this.

For example, in my application to view private messages, the url is www.example.com/messages/view/1 ... 1 being the message id.

I would really like to change this just to be www.example.com/messages/view as i feel having the message id in the url will allow users to manipulate the url to view any private message one the site.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: If you don't want just anyone to read a message, implement authorization. "Security through obscurity" never works.

Comment: How will you know which message to display if you don't have the ID? Just write some code that makes sure users can only read their own messages, instead of hiding the ID from the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the ID in the URL then the only way would be to POST it via a form.

This is pretty pointless however as the ID will be visible one way or another.

Instead you should focus on validation on the page that loads the message from the ID. Check on that page that the message ID exists and that the user has access to that message, if not then show an error.

This is a better approach.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes more sense that what i was looking at, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to control this from base. When you are preparing message to show - check the adress user. If it's like userid in session - show message, else die('Access denied');.

Or take message from base in that way: "Select * from messages where id = $id and userto = $user". And take $user variable from session data. (  $user = $this->session->userdata('userid'); ) if you have it there. If current user is not adress user - he couldn't recireve message.